# Page featured image not showing on home page

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm creating my own theme, my little practice. I added `the_post_thumbnail` in index.php page. All latest post's featured images are showing on home page except `Page featured image`.

While I added `the_post_thumbnail` in index.php, I don't understand why the page featured image is not showing up on the home page.

Any suggestions?
**edited post**
***i think my code not supported page featured image. here's my code***

```
 <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?>
                <div class="post">
                    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="entry"> 
               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="image image-full">
                            <?php  the_post_thumbnail('full');  ?>
               </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                         <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail` displays the featured image for a given single post. What do you define as the "page featured image"

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail` can be used for page featured image too, but you will need to call it outside of the loop, (this also apply to `the_title()`, `the_description()` etc..) In your code you call it in the loop and it will retrieve posts images, call it before `if( have_posts) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd need to get the **actual page object** and find the ID from there. Then, you can pass that ID to `the_post_thumbnail()`, otherwise I think the ID of a post in the loop will be used, not the actual home page. Try this `$page_object = get_queried_object();` to get info about your home page.

Comment: Dear, Dan and Peter goosen, see it and now tell is this code support page featured image code???

Comment: Where exactly are you adding a featured image in the admin area?

Comment: yeah. I add featured image via "set featured image" option. it works fine on posts...

Comment: I think you need to try the code I suggested. The featured image of the blog page will not be used in the loop, you have to get this using the ID of the page you're on, which you can find using `get_queried_object()`

Comment: Mr.Dan can u edit it in my code or give hint of using this object?? I'm not understanding it. please if you try one more time...

Comment: See what this outputs: `print_r( get_queried_object() ); `

Comment: your query printing variables generated by array.

Comment: Yes, inside that object you should see "ID", just pass that ID to this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: thanx for help.